# Multivariate WaveNet: how make residual connection input and output size same?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, time-series, conv-neural-network, lstm

Im trying to make multivariate Wavenet implementation which has 2 channels and 32 filters. But this gives error when creating the residual connection inside the dilation layer.

The model:

```
# Multivariate WaveNet from chatGPT
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, Activation, Add
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

# Parameters
num_channels=2
input_shape = (None, num_channels)  # Input shape for multivariate time series
num_filters = 32
num_layers = 8

# Define the dilation blocks
def residual_block(x, dilation_rate):
    # Dilated causal convolution
    conv = Conv1D(filters=num_filters, kernel_size=2, dilation_rate=dilation_rate, padding='causal')(x)
    tanh_out = Activation('tanh')(conv)
    sigmoid_out = Activation('sigmoid')(conv)
    merged = tf.multiply(tanh_out, sigmoid_out)
    
    # 1x1 convolution to mix the results
    out = Conv1D(filters=num_filters, kernel_size=1, padding='same')(merged)
    
    # Residual connection
    x = Add()([x, out])
    
    return x

# Build the multivariate WaveNet model
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
x = input_layer

for i in range(num_layers):
    x = residual_block(x, 2**i)

# Output layer for each channel
output_layers = Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=1, padding='same')(x)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layers)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

The problem is `x = Add()([x, out])` because out is the result of applying 32 filters while x comes from the input and contains only 2 values.

The error is:

```
---> 44     x = residual_block(x, 2**i)
...
ValueError: Inputs have incompatible shapes. Received shapes 
---> 35 x = Add()([x, out])
...
(None, 2) and (None, 32)
```

How can the residual connection me made to be same size?

In this thread, https://www.quora.com/In-a-residual-Convolutional-net-how-is-output-size-of-shortcut-connection-matched-to-output-size-of-combination-of-corresponding-convolutional+pooling-layer - a suggestion is made that 'They use a special projection matrix W that projects some part of the input to the output. So there isn't an exact match, but still the shortcut connection gets many of the weights "across".'

How can this be implemented in Tensorflow?

Edit: Alternativly - should this be done with 2Dconvolutions?